# change a view after checked a checkbox

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, checkbox

I have a view that changes content without changing the overall view,
(change a portion of the view)
here is my code:

**Models:**

```
public class DisplayData
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public DisplayData(int ID)
    {
        this.ID = ID;
    }
}
```

**Controllers:**

```
    public ActionResult PartialDemo(string Data)
    {
        List<DisplayData> Display = new List<DisplayData>();

        if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
        {
            if (Data == "1")
            {
                Display.Add(new DisplayData(3));
                Display.Add(new DisplayData(4));
            }
            else
            {
                Display.Add(new DisplayData(5));
                Display.Add(new DisplayData(6));
            }
            return PartialView("PartialDemoUC", Display);
        }
        else
        {
            Display.Add(new DisplayData(1));
            Display.Add(new DisplayData(2));
            return View("PartialDemo", Display);
        }
     }
```

**PartialDemoUC.cshtml**

```
 @model IEnumerable<dynamic>

 @foreach(var items in Model)
 {
     @items.ID    
 }
```

**PartialDemo.cshtml:**

```
  @model IEnumerable<AppTwitter.Models.DisplayData>
  @{
      ViewBag.Title = "PartialDemo";
   }

   <script src="../../Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js" type="text/javascript"> </script>
    @Ajax.ActionLink("**Link_1**", "PartialDemo", "PartialDemo", new {Data= "1" }, new   AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "rsvpmsg" })
    @Ajax.ActionLink("**Link_2**", "PartialDemo", "PartialDemo", new {Data= "2" }, new   AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "rsvpmsg" })

    <div id="rsvpmsg">
    @{ Html.RenderPartial("PartialDemoUC", this.Model);}
    </div>
```

I will change `Link_1` and `Link_2` by a `checkbox:` if `chechbox` is checked it's like the link is clicked
how can i do this ?

I am sorry for my bad English.

Comment: What happens when the checkbox is unchecked? Is it the same as if the link was clicked? Do you need to distinguish the fact whether the checkbox is checked or not inside your PartialDemo action? If not why are you using checkboxes at all?

Comment: @Darin Dimitrov if checkbox is unchecked is same if the link is not clicked, yes i want to distinguish the fact whether the checkbox is checked inside my PartialDemo action, Thanks Darin

Comment: You seem to be contradicting yourself: you are saying that you want to distinguish the fact whether the checkbox is checked inside your PartialDemo action and on the other hand you say `if checkbox is unchecked is same if the link is not clicked`. But if the link is not clicked no AJAX request is sent at all and the controller action is not even invoked. So which one is it. I have posted an answer in which an AJAX request is always sent and the isChecked value passed as additional argument. If you don't want an AJAX request in this case you will have to adapt my code.

Comment: @Darin Dimitrov your code is very useful for me, i want the ajax request is sent if chexbox is checked, how can i update your code thanks Darin

Comment: Wrap the AJAX call inside an `if` condition: `if (isChecked) { $.ajax(...); }`.

Comment: @Darin Dimitrov congratulations Darin,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use standard checkboxes:

```
@model IEnumerable<AppTwitter.Models.DisplayData>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "PartialDemo";
}

<div data-url="@Url.Action("PartialDemo", "PartialDemo")" id="checkboxes">
    @Html.CheckBox("Data1", new { data_value = "1" })
    @Html.CheckBox("Data2", new { data_value = "2" })
</div>

<div id="rsvpmsg">
    @{Html.RenderPartial("PartialDemoUC", this.Model);}
</div>
```

and then in a separate javascript file (that you need to reference) subscribe for the [`.change()`](http://api.jquery.com/change/) event of those checkboxes and trigger an AJAX request:

```
$(function () {
    $('#checkboxes :checkbox').change(function () {
        var value = $(this).data('value');
        var isChecked = $(this).is(':checked');
        var url = $('#checkboxes').data('url');
        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            type: 'POST',
            data: { data: value, isChecked: isChecked },
            success: function (result) {
                $('#rsvpmsg').html(result);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Now your controller action could take 2 parameters which will allow you in addition to knowing which checkbox was clicked, whether its value was checked or unchecked because contrary to a link a checkbox can have 2 possible states:

```
public ActionResult PartialDemo(string data, bool isChecked)
{
    ...
}
```

Oh and you no longer need the `jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js` script if you don't use the `Ajax.*` helpers anymore.